# Как вытащить cookie?

Tags: javascript

Раньше был у меня код javascript, сейчас не могу найти в нете. Короче, была такая тема, заходишь на страницу, в адресную строку вставляешь этот js код, и отображались куки страницы. Если кто знает, ответьте )

Comment: В нормальных браузерах есть возможность смотреть куки без дополнительных ухищрений через "Инструменты разработчика" (типа FireBug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie.split(';').join('\n'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    cookie.set = function (name,value,expires,path,domain,secure){
var today = new Date();
today.setTime( today.getTime() );
if(expires)
    expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var expires_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));

document.cookie = name + "=" +encodeURI( value ) +
    ( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) +
    ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) +
    ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
    ( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
```

};

```
cookie.get = function (name){
var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + '=');
var len = start + name.length + 1;
if ((!start) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0,name.length)))
    return null;
if (start == -1)
    return null;
var end = document.cookie.indexOf(';',len);
if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
if(end == start){
    return '';
}
return decodeURI(document.cookie.substring(len,end));
```

};

```
cookie.check = function (name){
return !!ka.cookie.get(name);
```

};

```
cookie.del = function(name){
ka.cookie.set(name,"",-1);
```

};